# The program 'make' is currently not installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make

I have my server Ubuntu 11.04  (VPS OVH ) and I want to install "eaccelerator". When I try to run `make install` I get the following message:

> The program 'make' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: apt-get install make

But whene I run `sudo apt-get install make` I get this message:

> E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate

I run `apt-get update`, and then run `sudo apt-get install make` only to get the same result. I've also tried to change my sources.list but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

`make` should be included in the  `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: whene i try to install this i get  Unable to locate package build-essential

Answer (score 1):

make is part of the build-essential package in Ubuntu. It is bundled with GCC ( C/C++ compiler) and a lot of other development tools.

Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and make will be installed.

Comment: whene i try to install this i get  Unable to locate package build-essential